# Prevent accidental close of browser window while submitting

Tags: javascript, php, forms, browser

I have a page, on which a user can submit a form, containing a video. I've placed a "please wait, uploading now" message while the video is uploading, but apparently, that isn't enough.

SO: I want to make sure that the user doesn't accidentally navigate away from the page, so I've used this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Please make sure, the video has finished uploading before closing this window";
 };
```

There's just a problem: The system contains two separate .php files; a form and a upload/thank-you page. This means that if I place the code on the form, it executes the code too early (when the submit-button is pressed) and if I place it on in the send.php-file, it executes too late since the video has to upload before the head-tag is run.

Any good ideas?

*P.S. A possible solution could be to place the code on the form page and call the page using AJAX and the file handling ability workaround, but I have a feeling that this workaround might have caused dropped videos - so I play it safe.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Situation solved!**

I removed the submit-functionality of the button and replaced it with this:

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Send video" onclick="sendInformation();" />
```

I then created a javascript, which was submitting the information, but at the same time, initializing the onbeforeunload-code.

```
document.getElementById("pleasewait").style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   return "Please make sure, the video has finished uploading before closing this window."; 
};
```

It also has the undesired effect, that the onbeforeunload-code is invalidated, the moment the upload.php page has loaded completely - so the user isn't asked twice when closing a succesful upload.

It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the JS code when the user submits the form?

```
<form action="upload.php">
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
  // Validate the data, copy the file, etc.

  echo '<script>window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { return "Please make sure, the video has finished uploading before closing this window"; }</script>';
?>
```

That should work. However, I think you should give the option to leave:

```
<?php
  echo '<script>window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { return confirm("Do you want to leave?"); }</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Alas, it didn't work. The code is not executed until a succesful upload. However, I just got it working 5 minutes ago; please see the answer above...